# SimpleSchema unable to set specific error message for given validation

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I have this very basic model with just one field `name` that I want to validtate against a regex:

```
const Projects = new ProjectsCollection('projects');

Projects.schema = new SimpleSchema({
    _id         : {type: String, regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id},
    name        : {
        type : String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+((\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+))?$/
    }
});

Projects.attachSchema(Projects.schema);
```

When the validation fails I get back a validation error saying that `regex failed for Name` which is undesirable for me because it's ambiguous and the user has no idea what exactly I need him to enter.

I tried adding the following with no success:

```
Projects.schema.messages({
    "regEx name": [{
        msg: "test error message"
    }]
});
```

This one however..works but the problem is that I could have any other model with a name field and it will spit out the same error message for all of them (and I plan on having another model with a `name` field):

```
SimpleSchema.messages({
    "regEx name": [{
        msg: "test error message"
    }]
});
```

I tried also with (no success):

```
SimpleSchema.messages({
    "regEx projects.name": [{
        msg: "test error message"
    }]
});
```

I insert via methods and here's my insert code:

```
export const insert = new ValidatedMethod({
    name                  : 'projects.insert',
    mixins                : [simpleSchemaMixin],
    schema                : Projects.simpleSchema().pick([
        'name'
    ]),
    schemaValidatorOptions: {
        clean : true,
        filter: false
    },
    run({name}) {
        return Projects.insert({
            name
        }, null);
    },
});
```

Any ideas on how am I supposed to configure my validation messages so that I can target them for specific fields?

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#customizing-validation-messages) for the special case of `regex` messages:

In your case you should try:

```
Projects.schema.messages({
  "regEx name": [
    {
      exp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+((\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+))?$/ , 
      msg: "test error message"
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Same generic error unfortunately: `Name failed regular expression validation`

Comment: Do you set the messages *before* you attach the schema?

Comment: I just tried with both to make sure. I'm suspecting that `ValidatedMethod` is creating a new Schema which does not make use of my messages.

Comment: Oh ya, I think you're right. You're only using the definition of the `name` field from your schema and the messages are attached one level up.

Answer (score 0):

This answer and question applies to v1 of meteor-simpl-schema

I had the same problem and this worked for me. I think that custom messages are instance based - are bound only to one simplSchema instance. Then in your validated-method, [pick()](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/blob/master/simple-schema.js#L660) will create a new SimplSchema instance, without your custom messages.

I needed to manually add a custom messages from the "parent" schema.
In your case like this:

```
const insertProjectSchema = Projects.schema.pick('name');
insertProjectSchema.messages(Projects.schema._messages);

export const insert = new ValidatedMethod({
    name                  : 'projects.insert',
    mixins                : [simpleSchemaMixin],
    schema                : insertProjectSchema,
    schemaValidatorOptions: {
        clean : true,
        filter: false
    },
    run({name}) {
        return Projects.insert({
            name
        }, null);
    },
});
```